# How to know the exact line number that produce an exception

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

To get error report on iOS/Android deployed app i use grijjy solutions (https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/02/09/build-your-own-error-reporter-part-1-ios/). The problem is that it's gave me the function name where the error occur but not the exact line number. For example I often have this error:

```
Argument out of range
At address: $002CDD4B (Generics.Collections.TListHelper.CheckItemRange(Integer) + 62)

Call stack:
MyApp $00BB153D Grijjy.Errorreporting.backtrace(Pointer*, Integer) + 8
MyApp $00BB1427 Grijjy.Errorreporting.TgoExceptionReporter.GlobalGetExceptionStackInfo(TExceptionRecord*) + 74
MyApp $001C4D83 Sysutils.Exception.RaisingException(TExceptionRecord*) + 38
MyApp $001E903D Sysutils.RaiseExceptObject(TExceptionRecord*) + 44
MyApp $001B0D9D _RaiseAtExcept(TObject*, Pointer) + 164
MyApp $001B1007 _RaiseExcept(TObject*) + 14
MyApp $002CDD4B Generics.Collections.TListHelper.CheckItemRange(Integer) + 62
MyApp $0059D4B3 Fmx.Controls.TControl.PaintChildren() + 222
MyApp $005BB987 Fmx.Controls.TControl.PaintInternal().DoPaintInternal(Pointer) + 1162
MyApp $005BC165 Fmx.Controls.TControl.PaintInternal().PaintAndClipChild(Pointer) + 500
MyApp $005B8F09 Fmx.Controls.TControl.PaintInternal() + 376
MyApp $007569D5 Fmx.Forms.TCustomForm.PaintRects(Types.TRectF const*, Integer) + 1008
MyApp $0074A001 __stub_in660v62__ZN3Fmx5Forms17TCommonCustomForm10PaintRectsEPKN6System5Types6TRectFEi + 24
MyApp $0068257D Fmx.Platform.Ios.TFMXView3D.drawRect(Iosapi.Foundation.NSRect) + 204
MyApp $00C2BA57 DispatchToDelphi + 82
MyApp $00C2B927 dispatch_first_stage_intercept + 18
QuartzCore $246A9F63 <redacted> + 106
QuartzCore $2468E551 <redacted> + 204
QuartzCore $2468E211 <redacted> + 24
QuartzCore $2468D6D1 <redacted> + 368
QuartzCore $2468D3A5 <redacted> + 520
QuartzCore $24686B2B <redacted> + 138
CoreFoundation $220456C9 <redacted> + 20
CoreFoundation $220439CD <redacted> + 280
CoreFoundation $22043DFF <redacted> + 958
CoreFoundation $21F93229 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
CoreFoundation $21F93015 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
GraphicsServices $23583AC9 GSEventRunModal + 160
UIKit $26667189 UIApplicationMain + 144
MyApp $003CBF15 Iosapi.Uikit.UIApplicationMain(Integer, Byte**, Pointer, Pointer) + 8
MyApp $00676843 Fmx.Platform.Ios.TPlatformCocoaTouch.Run() + 70
MyApp $006767FB __stub_in92s__ZN3Fmx8Platform3Ios19TPlatformCocoaTouch3RunEv + 10
MyApp $0074628F Fmx.Forms.TApplication.Run() + 182
MyApp $00C2B893 main + 246
$1FE2EF0F
```

So with this report I know that I have something wrong in the function `Fmx.Controls.TControl.PaintChildren()` but the exception (**Argument out of range**) is too wide to know exactly with line and instruction is responsible of the problem. I m unable to reproduce this error in development as its appear only sometime in deployed device.

Comment: Wild guessing... argument out of range is thrown from `System.Generics.Collections.TListHelper.CheckItemRange`, so some list inside `PaintChildren` is being updated while iteratiing and no longer has item at requested index. This usually happens if you touch UI from background thread.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar thanks yes I was thinking the same, but I promise you I don't touch anything from background thread. Delphi do internally stuff like Screen.forms[0] without verifying if 0 is out of range but I m suspicious its this. Other option is that some event in Ios are "sometime" launched from background thread (Like begameactive for example) but I m also suspicious about it. So right noy my task is to know exactly with list cause the out of range

Comment: I agree with Dalija. I have had a similar Issues with controls disappearing while they were being updated/realigned. This happened because a control changed its parentID during the update, hence changed the list of controls. Lesson from this: Your list.Count changes during the iteration of the list. debug into the loop, and check the count each time you go through the loop. Don't put a breakpoint inside the loop, as recursion will probably mess things up. Memorize the iteration value count before the Count was changed. Next find out what changes the list and thus how to fix the bug.problem.

Comment: @H.Hasenack yes but how you explain that this exception is raised only at very rare case, never happened in development  and only on very rare ocasion on production. It's clear that something change the count but what ?

Comment: Indeed, that is the price winning question. 1st step would be to find a way to reproduce it with confidence. Next, I would put a breakpoint on the ControlsList.CHanged method (or something alike) sou you see what routine modified the list on the call stack. I cannot say what it is from the provided source code.

Comment: @H.Hasenack: no way to reproduce it with confidence, and i try and try :( for now i want to locate via the log the exact line number that raise the exception (without patching the fmx).

Comment: Debugging patn events can be a real pain. I suggest using 2 monitors, one for debugging and one for the subject app. This avoids being painted over and over again because delphi pops in front of it. Having the exact line number won't help, you actually have to find the control that is destroyed/removed from the list during painting.

Comment: @H.Hasenack yes a real pain this why I would like to know the best way to do it (and here its about debugging iOS app it s horrible to debug, so much slow). But the main problem is that I m unable to reproduce the bug, i don't add/remove controls from the list during painting so it's clearly a very strange bug. But the bug is here, because I receive the bug report everyday from different devices, so i can t ignore it simply because i can not reproduce it, so I must fully work on the bug report to have a clue where the bug is

Comment: @Stephane Since, your question is rather specific about how to find which line of code triggered exception I wrote some additional hints that might help you in a blog post https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2019/01/fixing-firemonkey-heisenbugs.html

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar wooow very great article! thanks Dalija ... you are right at some moment you just have to give up :( I spend an entire week end to try to find out where the problem is, i have no clue! its happen only on iOS device so its sure its not in my own code else the error will be also raised in android. I have only 2 ideas: 1) the memory get corrupted in iOS (i was able to reproduce it one time, the device was sleeping for 2 days, i wake up the device and launch my app and then its crash) ... 2) one of the event in iOS is launched in a background thread

Comment: loki = Stephane? If so please ask SO support to merge your accounts

Comment: @StefanGlienke yes loki = stephane but loki is using facebook to login and from my work facebook is blacklisted so i was forced to create another account :(

Comment: @Stephane You can easily add a 2nd login - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290774/587106

Answer (score 0):

The `+62`value in the log is the byte offset of the issue, therefore you can inspect the assembler and look at the offset of the method in the stack, presumably `$0059D4B3` and look for the 222nd byte, you should be able to backtrack which operation caused the issue by running the debugger and breaking in that method: the assmebler shown should be sufficient to understand where in your code lies the issue.

Line numbers are difficult to be traced in unmanaged programs unless they are supported by the vendor out of the box. Have you tried madExcept?

We are currently using Eurekalog, but line numbers are not available for our projects. If I am not remembering wrong, madExcept had that feature.

Comment: Thanks Pier, but Eurekalog and madExcept work only for windows :( also When i have deployed the application, is their a way to localise the line without recompiling the source just because I need to run the debugger ?

Comment: I wasn't aware they are windows only tools. However, the answer is "maybe": if you recompile the project with the very same options you **might** get the same assembly code. I say **might** as EMB new compilers are not determistic, therefore every build is different (except digital signature of course). You can try, however, if your method is not so complex, you could also start doing some static analysis in order to locate the offending list. Finally, when the issue occurs at customer site only, place additional exception handling targeting more precise locations.